# java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase:

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

Al ejecutar este metodo en un dispositivo android me lanza el siguiente error: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase:(path)

---

```
 public synchronized void actualizarRegistro(Registro registro) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMNA_ID,registro.getId());
        values.put(COLUMNA_NOMBRE,registro.getNombre());
        if(db.isOpen()){
            int i = db.update(TABLA_REGISTROS, ////Al ejecutar esto lanza el error
                    values,
                    COLUMNA_ID+"=?",
                    new String[]{String.valueOf(obtenerID(registro.getId()))});
            db.close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Que linea de código indica el problema, revisa el LogCat por favor.

Comment: la marco con un comentario, es la linea:int i = db.update(TABLA_REGISTROS,

Answer (score 0):

agregando:db.acquireReference(); antes de update funciona, el metodo quedaria asi:

```
 public synchronized void actualizarRegistro(Registro registro) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMNA_ID,registro.getId());
        values.put(COLUMNA_NOMBRE,registro.getNombre());
        if(db.isOpen()){
            db.acquireReference()//////Agregando esto antes de actualizar se arregla el problema
            int i = db.update(TABLA_REGISTROS, 
                    values,
                    COLUMNA_ID+"=?",
                    new String[]{String.valueOf(obtenerID(registro.getId()))});
            db.close();
        }

    }
```